# Can you embed Links for SVGs after fadeIn Jquery?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, href, fadein, fadeout

Greetings and welcome to my first question. hoping to answer some as my experience grows, but t'il then, I am in someone's debt.

Upon page load for the first time, users will see a variety of logos, and depending on which they choose, the other logos will change by way of jquery fadeIn and fadeOut functions.

My aim is to have a user click an initial logo, where it and the other logos change, and the new logos/images will have URL's behind them which, when clicked, direct the user to the relevant page.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how the new image functions as a link, rather than the jquery behind the old image. What currently happens is the code sticks to the fadeOut/fadeIn.

Here is the code I am using with images replaced with Lorem Picsum for the initial logos and the follow-up logos. The images I shall be using are SVG images - and I am toying with the idea of embedding links within the SVG code of the fadeIn images, but know they wouldn't work until I can cancel the fadeIn jquery script.

**Ideas tried:**
using .stop within the function at various points
added href links at various points in the code (this is how I learn, it seems! Break it until it works)
Searched various websites where the function I am after is similar.

Think this may be enough information, but if I'm missing anything, let me know, please :)

Many thanks to those that may/can help.

```js
$(function() { //For first Logo
  $("#img").click(function() {
    $("#img").fadeOut(100, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/010").fadeIn()
      $("#img1").fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/020").fadeIn()
        $("#img2").fadeOut(100, function() {
          $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/030").fadeIn()
        }) //Closes #img2 
      }) //Closes #img1
      ;
    }) //closes #img
    ;
  }) //closes .click
}); //closes first Logo jquery

$(function() { //For second Logo
  $("#img1").click(function() {
    $("#img").fadeOut(100, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/040").fadeIn()
      $("#img1").fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/050").fadeIn()
        $("#img2").fadeOut(100, function() {
          $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/060").fadeIn()
        }) //Closes #img2 
      }) //Closes #img1
      ;
    }) //closes #img
    ;
  }) //closes .click
}); //closes second Logo jquery

$(function() { //For third Logo
  $("#img2").click(function() {
    $("#img").fadeOut(100, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/070").fadeIn()
      $("#img1").fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/080").fadeIn()
        $("#img2").fadeOut(100, function() {
          $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/090").fadeIn()
        }) //Closes #img2 
      }) //Closes #img1
      ;
    }) //closes #img
    ;
  }) //closes .click
}); //closes third Logo jquery
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" ID="img" width="300" height="100"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" ID="img1" width="300" height="100"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300" ID="img2" width="300" height="100" display="none"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<h3> Would like each initial image to change to the new source as defined in each .attr. When the new images loads in, it will then link to a new page and not cycle the .fadeOut/.fadeIn query when the user clicks the initial image.</h3>
```

Comment: I might try using a script which changes the ID of my object, which I hope will then invalidate the original query. Lets hope so!

Answer (score 1):

The answer was:

```
    $(function() { //Open function for 1st (top) image
  $("#img").click(function() { //Click starts image change
    $("#img").fadeOut(200, function() { //Fades out 1st image
      $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/500").attr("id","img5").fadeIn(200).wrap("<a href='URL GOES HERE'>") //Swap 1st image, ID and adds URL
      $("#img1").fadeOut(200, function() { //Fades out 2nd image
        $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/600").attr("id","img6").fadeIn(200).wrap("<a href='URL GOES HERE'>") //Swap 2nd image, ID and adds URL
        $("#img2").fadeOut(200, function() { //Fades out 3rd image
          $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/700").attr("id","img7").fadeIn(200).wrap("<a href='URL GOES HERE'>")//Swap 3rd image, ID and adds URL
          $("#img3").fadeOut(200, function() { //Fade Out 4th image for Brand Support Logo set
            $(this).attr('src', "https://picsum.photos/800").fadeIn(300).click(function() {//Fades in "reset" image, adds click.
              $("#img5").fadeOut(200).attr('src',"https://picsum.photos/100").attr("id","img").fadeIn(300).unwrap();//Fades out new 1st image, resets ID and removes URL
                            $("#img6").fadeOut(200).attr('src',"https://picsum.photos/200").attr("id","img1").fadeIn(300).unwrap();//Fades out new 2nd image, resets ID and removes URL
              $("#img7").fadeOut(200).attr('src',"https://picsum.photos/300").attr("id","img2").fadeIn(300).unwrap();//Fades out new 3rd image, resets ID and removes URL
              }); //Closes "reset"
            }); //Closes img3 fade
          }) //Closes img2 fade 
        }); //Closes img1 fade
      }); //Closes img fade
    }); //Closes click function
}); //Closes function
```

You add a .wrap statement, and then use callbacks to unwrap elements. In the fiddle, I have given explanations to each codelines purpose and what it does.